# IOException thrown when processing xsd dependencies in maven

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a problem while processing .xsd file during my maven build.
I use jaxb2 plugin but I have to download external dependiencies from my .xsd files. The problem is that these dependencies (.xsd) are from enviroment which is unstable and very often my build fails because maven cannot download xsd file. How to configure jaxb plugin to force him to try download xsd few times to prevent build failure?

Part of my pom.xml configuration:

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <strict>false</strict>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xsetters</arg>
                        <arg>-XenumValue</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-fluent-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${jaxb.fluentapi.version}</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.9.3</version>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/jaxb</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>bindings.xml</include>
                    </bindingIncludes>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <fileset>
                                <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory. -->
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/orbeons</directory>
                                <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes. -->
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.xsd</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.basedir}/generated-sources/orbeons</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Specifying-What-To-Compile) does not support such a feature. (And neither does the [`maven-download-plugin`](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin) nor even the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)).

Three solutions come into my mind at the moment (plus two and a half inspired by [LIttle Ancient Forest Kami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999165/little-ancient-forest-kami)'s comment) [Numbers reflect the precedence of what I would do]:

- Use a CI tool (Jenkins, etc.) that supports retry on job failure. [1]
- Handmade:

  - Use the [GMavenPlus plugin](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) with a script ... [2]
  - Use the [Maven AntRun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) with a script ... [3]
  - Use the [Exec Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) with a program ... [5]

  ... that performs the download and retry and bind it to the `generate-resources` phase in your project's POM.

  - [Create a Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) with appropriate parameters (`url`, `outputDirectory`, `retryCount`) that uses the `maven-download-plugin` and performs the retry. Bind its goal to the `generate-resources` phase in your project's POM. [4]
  - Create a `check-download` Maven project that uses the `maven-download-plugin` bound to the `generate-resources` phase to download the `.xsd`. [6]

    Create a shell script that contains the following (in pseudo code):

    ```
    download:
      counter++
      <check-download project>/mvn generate-resources
      if error and counter < maxRetryCount goto download

    if not error
      <your project>/mvn ...
    else
      display appropriate error message
    ```

There is also a question [Maven download retry?](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@geronimo.apache.org/msg03649.html) from 2005. Unanswered.

Comment: Because they only put it there when they realized what happens, because it's not enforced by Maven itself (no checks or build failures on using it) and nobody reads docs, right? ;-) As for other options: antTask and/or exec Maven call?

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami "_nobody reads docs_" – very right! Unfortunately. Ant? Really? With Maven we luckily got rid of Ant/Ivy's configuration verbosity and now we shall reintroduce it there? ;) BTW, I've read the term "_Javavore_" in your profile for the first time ever. I love it! Pushed you to 1000 for that.

Comment: *BTW: I wonder why plugins don't respect the "Plugin Naming Convention and Apache Maven Trademark" mentioned there in big bold letters.*

Please read [this](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/26#issuecomment-66928927). The plugin was named this way long before this naming convention was established. Renaming now will damage the community. So Apache is free to send me a cease-and-desist letter and I'll just shut down the project then as I'm kind of tired of this "you don't respect our convention" bullying.

Comment: @lexicore I see. Sounds reasonable. Please don't shut down. It wasn't my intention to bully you. I was just wondering. I can imagine that mentioning or linking these reasons on a more prominent (e.g. first Wiki) page is likely to prevent comments like these, including mine, in the future.

Comment: @GeroldBroser thank you! A pleasant move on your part! Ant because I know at least one Ant magician who did things with it quickly and well. After your comment, yes, in your case a bad move. :-)

Comment: @GeroldBroser No problem. :) Yes, Wiki/front page would make sense, will do that.

Answer (score 3):

Author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) here.

You have two parts here: managing the downloads of external resources and compiling the schemas, rewriting "external" links to local files.

The first (managing downloads) is not in the scope of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin), the second is supported with 
[catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs).

In short, you can create a catalog file like this:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org" "w3c"
```

Or this:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net" "maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc"
```

And use this file to "rewrite" absolute links to local files or resources within Maven artifacts:

```
<configuration>
    <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
</configuration>
```

As for the first part, I don't think managing downloads with retries, continuations and all other stuff should be in the scope of the JAXB2 Maven plugin.

ps. You don't need `build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source` with `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, source directory is added automatically.